# How to rotate a Rectangular object under a fixed Position

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformation, rotations

I am looking for some help with a project I am working on.

I am looking to make a fast program for gluing 3 edges of a rectangular piece of card. The program will need to be much faster when gluing before it sets. Therefore, I would like to add some rotation into it so the the machine doesn't have to slow down and stop at the end of each side.

I have included some more information below regarding the project:

**Use case:**
I would like to set up a gluing apparatus to glue along 3 sides of a rectangular piece of  card, this will be held using a mechanical arm  in the center of the card.

**Task:** 
This is a little more complicated than what it may at first seem, I would like the card to follow a fixed path (direct) along the first, second and third edge WHILST rotating over the whole process by a 180 degrees. This will help the mechanical system glue faster as it does not have to stop and then rotate before continuing on to the next side.

If someone could help me by suggesting a formula for this to calculate the relationship between movement between the coordinates ((x1,y1) to (x2,y2), (x2,y2) to (x3,y3), (x3,y3) to (x4,y4)) whilst keeping the gluing nozzle along the edge. (It would be preferable that the machine would rotate by the average of 60 degrees by the end of each side.) The machine will be moving in a positive rotation (anticlockwise looking from above).
I have researched transformations as I think this may possibly be along the route to the answer although there seems to be very little information for calculating coordinates for angles other than 45,90,180,270 degrees etc. Any method that may work is welcome.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an NC machine application?

Comment: No this is a collaborative robot.

Comment: Can you provide us a diagram (a rough sketch would do) showing the present state of operation of your system? When I say the present state of operation, I mean the one that slows down and stops at the end of each edge. I would also like to know how the pen that issues and applies glue to the rectangle moves.